# declaring using a variable using new vs normal decleration and nature of Integer ( boxing / unboxing)

Tags: java, integer, int

Guys can anybody explain me this nature of new and the use of Integer

```
Integer i = new Integer(-10);
Integer j = new Integer(-10);
Integer k = -10;
Integer l=-10;
System.out.println(i==j);
System.out.println(k==l);
```

answer is false true

next

```
    Integer a=128;
    Integer b=128;
    Integer c=127;
    Integer d=127;
    System.out.println(a==b);
    System.out.println(c==d);
```

answer am getting is false true.
Can anybody explain this nature.
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you're *always* creating new `Integer` objects and assigning those references to `i` and `j`. For `k` and `l` you're using autoboxing, which *sometimes* creates new objects and *sometimes* doesn't.

In your second example, you're *just* using autoboxing - but with different values, which demonstrates the "sometimes" from above.

From [section 5.1.7 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.
>
> Ideally, boxing a given primitive value p, would always yield an identical reference. In practice, this may not be feasible using existing implementation techniques. The rules above are a pragmatic compromise. The final clause above requires that certain common values always be boxed into indistinguishable objects. The implementation may cache these, lazily or eagerly. For other values, this formulation disallows any assumptions about the identity of the boxed values on the programmer's part. This would allow (but not require) sharing of some or all of these references.
>
> This ensures that in most common cases, the behavior will be the desired one, without imposing an undue performance penalty, especially on small devices. Less memory-limited implementations might, for example, cache all char and short values, as well as int and long values in the range of -32K to +32K.

Comment: Sir what do you mean by sometimes creates new objects and sometimes it doesn't ? 
and in the second example as you said the case the range  thing i.e. -128 to 127, the result r1==r2 will be true, fine. But what about the values of a , b which are 128 and they are same, still am getting a FALSE ?

Comment: @GursahibSahni: Did you read the section from the JLS? I thought it made it pretty clear. Basically there's a cache of predefined values for "small" integers - those will be used for boxing small integers, but boxing larger values will create a new object each time.

Comment: sir, so you are trying to say that for large integers each time a new object is created and hence the result is a FALSE value?

Comment: @GursahibSahni: Yes, exactly. (Where "large" is implementation-specific.)

Comment: and by the way when you say large integers
large as in which are not short?

Comment: @GursahibSahni: Again, *please* read my answer closely. It's all in there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14677/discussion-between-gursahib-sahni-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @GursahibSahni: No, I don't have time to chat right now. All the information is in the answer, mostly in the bit quoted in the spec.